# I need only eight room on add button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code in witch I only want to add 8 rooms when current index is greater than 8 gives an alert  i.e you can't add more than 8 rooms. The problem is that when I click at index 8, its shows alert but after that I click a add room it append room 10 please help
this is my code on js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FhyLX/

```html
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<div id="guestsRooms" class="clear">
    <label class="label1" for="guestsRoomsSelect">How many people</label>
    <span>
        <span>
            <select id="guestsRoomsSelect" name="GuestsRooms" >
                <option selected="selected" value="RB=1&RA1=1&RCA1=0">1 adult</option>
                <option value="RB=1&RA1=2&RCA1=0">2 adults in 1 room</option>
                <option value="RB=1&RA1=3&RCA1=0">3 adults in 1 room</option>
                <option value="RB=1&RA1=4&RCA1=0">4 adults in 1 room</option>
                <option value="RB=2&RA1=2&RCA1=0&RA2=2&RCA1=0">2 adults in 2 rooms</option>
                <option value="0">Need more rooms or have children?</option>
            </select>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>

   <div id="roomconfig" class="roomconfig_fc">           
   <div id="Addition"></div>
   <div class="btnWrap">
     <a class="addRoom"  style="background-image:none; color:darkred;height:20px; margin-left:20px" href="javascript:void(0);"><img alt="" src="Images/SearchBox/image1.png" class="addimage"  />Add room</a>
   </div>
</div>
    <a id="btnSubmit" class="a" href="javascript:void(0);">Find a hotel</a>
</form>
</body>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 1;
    var IsRoomPreSelected = false;
    var currentIndex = 1;
    var RoomsString = "";

    $('#roomconfig').hide();
    $("#guestsRoomsSelect").find("option[value='2-1']").attr("selected", "selected");
    $('#adults').prop("selectedIndex", 1);
    $('#hc_f_children').prop("selectedIndex", 0);

    $('#guestsRoomsSelect').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === '0' && IsRoomPreSelected === false) {
            var $var2 = '<div id="AdultWrapper_' + counter + '" class="class1"> <div class="wrapadults" style="float:left"> <label class="lbl_sm" style="font-size: 0.75em" for="adults">Adults</label>'
            $var2 = $var2 + '<span><select id="AdultDropdown_' + counter + '" class="t_adults" style="margin-left:0px;margin-right:12px; border-right: 0.5px solid #FFFFFF;"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2" selected="selected">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option></select></span></div></div>'
            $var2 = $var2 + '<div id="ChildrenWrapper_' + counter + '" class="child" ><label class="lbl_sm" style="font-size: .75em; padding-left:3px; padding-right:2px;border-right:1px solid #fff;" for="children">Children</label><br/><span style="float: left;width: auto;padding-right:6px;border-right: 1px solid #fff;padding-bottom: 5px;margin: 0PX;"><select id="ChildrenDropdown_' + counter + '" class="tfo_evt_children " style="border-right: 0.5px solid #FFFFFF;margin-right:7px; width:40px;"><option value="0" selected="selected">0</option> <option value="1">1</option> <option value="2">2</option> <option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option> </select> </span><div id="ChildrenAgeWrapper_' + counter + '" class="ch"></div>';
            $("#Addition").prepend('<fieldset id="Roomesfieldset_' + counter + '" data-index="' + counter + '"><legend id="RoomLegend" >Room ' + currentIndex + ':</legend>' + $var2 + '</fieldset>');
            counter = counter + 1;
            IsRoomPreSelected = true;
            $('#roomconfig').show(300);
        }
        else if ($(this).val() === '0' && IsRoomPreSelected === true) {
            $('#roomconfig').show(300);
        }
        else {
            $('#roomconfig').hide(300);
        }
    });

    $(".addRoom").click(function () {
        currentIndex++;
        if('Room'+currentIndex+''>'Room8')
        {
        alert("you can't Add more than 8 rooms");
        }
        else
        {

        var $var1 = '<div id="AdultWrapper_' + counter + '" class="class1"> <div class="wrapadults" style="float:left"><span><select id="AdultDropdown_' + counter + '" class="t_adults" style="margin-left:0px;margin-right:12px; border-right: 0.5px solid #FFFFFF;"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2" selected="selected">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option></select></span></div></div>'
        $var1 = $var1 + '<div id="ChildrenWrapper_' + counter + '" id="child" > <span style="float: left;width: auto;padding-right:6px;border-right: 1px solid #fff;padding-bottom: 5px;margin: 0PX;"><select id="ChildrenDropdown_' + counter + '" class="tfo_evt_children " style="border-right: 0.5px solid #FFFFFF; margin-right:7px; width:40px;"><option value="0" selected="selected">0</option> <option value="1">1</option> <option value="2">2</option> <option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option> </select> </span><div id="ChildrenAgeWrapper_' + counter + '" class="ch"></div></div>'
        $var1 = $var1 + '<div class="btnrmv" id="' + counter + '"> <a id="RemoveRoomAnchor" href="javascript:void(0);" class="removeRoom" style="height:0px; margin:0px;float:right;position:relative;background-image:none; color:#b11500;font-weight:normal;font-size:0.77em;" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="Images/SearchBox/close.png" alt="Remove" /></a></div>';

        $("#Addition").append('<fieldset id="Roomesfieldset_' + counter + '" data-index="' + counter + '"><legend id="RoomLegend">Room ' + currentIndex + ':</legend>' + $var1 + '</fieldset>');
        counter = counter + 1;
        }

    });

    $("#Addition").on('click', '#RemoveRoomAnchor', function (e) {
        $(this).closest("[id^=Roomesfieldset]").remove();
        $("fieldset").each(function (index) {
            $(this).attr("data-index", index);
            var te = $(this).attr("data-index");
            $(this).children("legend").text('Rooms ' + (++index) + ' :');
            currentIndex = index;
        });
    });

    $("#Addition").on('change', '[id^=ChildrenDropdown]', function (e) {

        $parentElement = $(this).closest("[id^=ChildrenWrapper]").children("[id^=ChildrenAgeWrapper]");         
        var previousChildrenCount = $("#" + $parentElement.attr("id") + " input").size();
        var currentChildrenCount = $(this[this.selectedIndex]).val();
        if (currentChildrenCount > previousChildrenCount)
        {
            for (i = previousChildrenCount; i < currentChildrenCount; i++) 
            {
                var $ctrl = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', class: 'age', name: 'text', value: '', style: 'width:30px;' });
                $parentElement.append($ctrl);
            }
        }
        else if (currentChildrenCount < previousChildrenCount)
        {
            $("#" + $parentElement.attr("id") + " input:gt(" + (currentChildrenCount-1) + ")").remove();             
        }            

        if (currentChildrenCount === '0')
        {
            $("#" + $parentElement.attr("id") + " input").remove();          
        }

    });

    $("#btnSubmit").click(function (e)
    {

        // alert($("#guestsRoomsSelect").val());
        if (($("#guestsRoomsSelect").val()) == 0)
        {
            RoomsString = "";
            var Rooms = 0;
            $("[id^=Roomesfieldset]").each(function (index) {
                // Rooms = Rooms + parseInt($(this).attr("data-index"));
                Rooms = Rooms + 1;
                var adult = $(this).find("[id^=AdultDropdown]").val();
                var child = $(this).find("[id^=ChildrenDropdown]").val();
                //  RoomsString = RoomsString + "&RA" + $(this).attr("data-index") + "=" + adult;
                RoomsString = RoomsString + "&RA" + (index + 1) + "=" + adult;

                if (child > 0)
                {
                    var ageArray = new Array(child);

                    $(this).find("[id^=ChildrenAgeWrapper]").children().each(function (index) {
                        var childAge = $(this).val();
                        ageArray[index] = childAge;                            
                    });

                    //   RoomsString = RoomsString + "&RCA" + $(this).attr("data-index") + "=" + ageArray.toString();
                    RoomsString = RoomsString + "&RCA" + (index + 1) + "=" + ageArray.toString();
                }
                else
                {
                   // RoomsString = RoomsString + "&RCA" + $(this).attr("data-index") + "=" + 0;
                    RoomsString = RoomsString + "&RCA" + (index + 1) + "=" + 0;
                }
            });

            RoomsString = "&RC=" + Rooms + RoomsString;
        }
        else
        {
            RoomsString = $("#guestsRoomsSelect").val();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: I just changed the position of currentIndex and use = operator also and your code works please check this fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/FhyLX/3/

Comment: If any answer below worked for you, please mark it as accepted (See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)) for futur visitor to find the more adapted answer easily

Answer (score 3):

The result of two string comparison is not what you need : the string comparison is going to compare each character of both string, one by one, and at the end determine the result of your comparison.

### Example :

If *'Room10'* and *'Room8'* are compared, then when it will compare the two string, it will compare both *'R'*, both *'o'*, then again *'o'*, then both *'m'*, then it will compare *'1'* and *'8'*.

At that moment, *'1'* will be closer to the start of the alphabet than *'8'*, and then your test will return false, whatever the following character are.

See [this article](http://javascript.about.com/od/decisionmaking/a/des02.htm) for further details.

---

Use the `int` `currentIndex` instead :

```
if(currentIndex > 8)
{
   alert("you can't Add more than 8 rooms");
}
```

Comment: Can the user who voted down post a comment to help me improve my post?

Comment: Actually, it wont : the part of the code which create & append the room is on the `else` statement of this test; `return false` just prevent default action for the click (as `.preventDefault()` would). [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2kCZ/)

Answer (score 2):

After your alert you have to return false so that the code knows when to stop proceeding further.

```
alert("you can't Add more than 8 rooms");
return false;
```

Like this

```
if(currentIndex>7)
            {
            alert("you can't Add more than 8 rooms");
                return false;
            }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FhyLX/4/)

Comment: still room 10 can be added.

Comment: Then that `IF` needs to be fixed as well, so it should not focus only on 8 but anything beyond 8

Comment: problem with currentIndex postion and IF condition

Comment: Thank you all of you for giving me best solution and help me in increaseing my kknowlwdge..Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

first test if the room index is greater than 8 then increase the roomindex:

```
$(".addRoom").click(function () {
    if(currentIndex>8){ //test if greater than 8 
       alert("you can't Add more than 8 rooms");
       return false;
    } else {
       currentIndex++
       ... //add the rest of the code here
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following code in jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 1;
    var IsRoomPreSelected = false;
    var currentIndex = 1;
    var RoomsString = "";

    $('#roomconfig').hide();
    $("#guestsRoomsSelect").find("option[value='2-1']").attr("selected", "selected");
    $('#adults').prop("selectedIndex", 1);
    $('#hc_f_children').prop("selectedIndex", 0);

    $('#guestsRoomsSelect').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === '0' && IsRoomPreSelected === false) {
            var $var2 = '<div id="AdultWrapper_' + counter + '" class="class1"> <div class="wrapadults" style="float:left"> <label class="lbl_sm" style="font-size: 0.75em" for="adults">Adults</label>'
            $var2 = $var2 + '<span><select id="AdultDropdown_' + counter + '" class="t_adults" style="margin-left:0px;margin-right:12px; border-right: 0.5px solid #FFFFFF;"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2" selected="selected">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option></select></span></div></div>'
            $var2 = $var2 + '<div id="ChildrenWrapper_' + counter + '" class="child" ><label class="lbl_sm" style="font-size: .75em; padding-left:3px; padding-right:2px;border-right:1px solid #fff;" for="children">Children</label><br/><span style="float: left;width: auto;padding-right:6px;border-right: 1px solid #fff;padding-bottom: 5px;margin: 0PX;"><select id="ChildrenDropdown_' + counter + '" class="tfo_evt_children " style="border-right: 0.5px solid #FFFFFF;margin-right:7px; width:40px;"><option value="0" selected="selected">0</option> <option value="1">1</option> <option value="2">2</option> <option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option> </select> </span><div id="ChildrenAgeWrapper_' + counter + '" class="ch"></div>';
            $("#Addition").prepend('<fieldset id="Roomesfieldset_' + counter + '" data-index="' + counter + '"><legend id="RoomLegend" >Room ' + currentIndex + ':</legend>' + $var2 + '</fieldset>');
            counter = counter + 1;
            IsRoomPreSelected = true;
            $('#roomconfig').show(300);
        }
        else if ($(this).val() === '0' && IsRoomPreSelected === true) {
            $('#roomconfig').show(300);
        }
        else {
            $('#roomconfig').hide(300);
        }
    });

    $(".addRoom").click(function () {
        currentIndex++;
        $('[id$=hdf]').val(currentIndex);
        alert(currentIndex);
        alert($('[id$=hdf]').val());
        if($('[id$=hdf]').val()>='8')
        {
        alert("you can't Add more than 8 rooms");
        }
        else
        {

        var $var1 = '<div id="AdultWrapper_' + counter + '" class="class1"> <div class="wrapadults" style="float:left"><span><select id="AdultDropdown_' + counter + '" class="t_adults" style="margin-left:0px;margin-right:12px; border-right: 0.5px solid #FFFFFF;"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2" selected="selected">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option></select></span></div></div>'
        $var1 = $var1 + '<div id="ChildrenWrapper_' + counter + '" id="child" > <span style="float: left;width: auto;padding-right:6px;border-right: 1px solid #fff;padding-bottom: 5px;margin: 0PX;"><select id="ChildrenDropdown_' + counter + '" class="tfo_evt_children " style="border-right: 0.5px solid #FFFFFF; margin-right:7px; width:40px;"><option value="0" selected="selected">0</option> <option value="1">1</option> <option value="2">2</option> <option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option> </select> </span><div id="ChildrenAgeWrapper_' + counter + '" class="ch"></div></div>'
        $var1 = $var1 + '<div class="btnrmv" id="' + counter + '"> <a id="RemoveRoomAnchor" href="javascript:void(0);" class="removeRoom" style="height:0px; margin:0px;float:right;position:relative;background-image:none; color:#b11500;font-weight:normal;font-size:0.77em;" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="Images/SearchBox/close.png" alt="Remove" /></a></div>';

        $("#Addition").append('<fieldset id="Roomesfieldset_' + counter + '" data-index="' + counter + '"><legend id="RoomLegend">Room ' + currentIndex + ':</legend>' + $var1 + '</fieldset>');
        counter = counter + 1;
        }

    });

    $("#Addition").on('click', '#RemoveRoomAnchor', function (e) {
        $(this).closest("[id^=Roomesfieldset]").remove();
        $("fieldset").each(function (index) {
            $(this).attr("data-index", index);
            var te = $(this).attr("data-index");
            $(this).children("legend").text('Rooms ' + (++index) + ' :');
            currentIndex = index;
        });
    });

    $("#Addition").on('change', '[id^=ChildrenDropdown]', function (e) {

        $parentElement = $(this).closest("[id^=ChildrenWrapper]").children("[id^=ChildrenAgeWrapper]");         
        var previousChildrenCount = $("#" + $parentElement.attr("id") + " input").size();
        var currentChildrenCount = $(this[this.selectedIndex]).val();
        if (currentChildrenCount > previousChildrenCount)
        {
            for (i = previousChildrenCount; i < currentChildrenCount; i++) 
            {
                var $ctrl = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', class: 'age', name: 'text', value: '', style: 'width:30px;' });
                $parentElement.append($ctrl);
            }
        }
        else if (currentChildrenCount < previousChildrenCount)
        {
            $("#" + $parentElement.attr("id") + " input:gt(" + (currentChildrenCount-1) + ")").remove();             
        }            

        if (currentChildrenCount === '0')
        {
            $("#" + $parentElement.attr("id") + " input").remove();          
        }

    });

    $("#btnSubmit").click(function (e)
    {

        // alert($("#guestsRoomsSelect").val());
        if (($("#guestsRoomsSelect").val()) == 0)
        {
            RoomsString = "";
            var Rooms = 0;
            $("[id^=Roomesfieldset]").each(function (index) {
                // Rooms = Rooms + parseInt($(this).attr("data-index"));
                Rooms = Rooms + 1;
                var adult = $(this).find("[id^=AdultDropdown]").val();
                var child = $(this).find("[id^=ChildrenDropdown]").val();
                //  RoomsString = RoomsString + "&RA" + $(this).attr("data-index") + "=" + adult;
                RoomsString = RoomsString + "&RA" + (index + 1) + "=" + adult;

                if (child > 0)
                {
                    var ageArray = new Array(child);

                    $(this).find("[id^=ChildrenAgeWrapper]").children().each(function (index) {
                        var childAge = $(this).val();
                        ageArray[index] = childAge;                            
                    });

                    //   RoomsString = RoomsString + "&RCA" + $(this).attr("data-index") + "=" + ageArray.toString();
                    RoomsString = RoomsString + "&RCA" + (index + 1) + "=" + ageArray.toString();
                }
                else
                {
                   // RoomsString = RoomsString + "&RCA" + $(this).attr("data-index") + "=" + 0;
                    RoomsString = RoomsString + "&RCA" + (index + 1) + "=" + 0;
                }
            });

            RoomsString = "&RC=" + Rooms + RoomsString;
        }
        else
        {
            RoomsString = $("#guestsRoomsSelect").val();
        }
    });

});
```

Fiddel is ::[Fiddel](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Yt24r/)

and in html add the below code in form ::

```
<input type="hidden"  id="hdf"  />
```

Or if you dont want to add a hidden field then go for the following code:

```
if(currentIndex>=8)
        {
        alert("you can't Add more than 8 rooms");
            return false;
        }
```

Here is fiddel for it::[Fiddel](http://fiddle.jshell.net/46KLR/)

Comment: You've Fiddled with the spelling of Fiddle: `Fiddel`

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ updated... and thanks for giving your valuable time read my answer..